# Permission problems with Laravel's storage directory on CentOS 7. Changing permissions and ownship with chmod and chown does not solve it

Tags: laravel-5, centos7, php-deployer

I figured this out myself while I was revising my question, but I'm going to post my original question anyway with the solution in case it helps anyone else.

The solution has nothing to do with symbolic links or Deployer, but I'm going to leave my question as is in case someone came to the same problem in a similar way.

---

I'm trying to set up a Laravel 5.8 deployment using [Deployer](https://deployer.org/) on a CentOS 7 server.

The deployment is successful. The `storage` folder is set as a shared directory in my `deploy.php` file, so what it does it sets up the `storage` folder as a persistent shared folder between releases. It does this by creating a symbolic link to a shared `storage` folder for the releases.

There is a folder for the current release at `/var/www/test-laravel/current`, which is actually a symbolic link to the folder with the most recent release (in this case `/var/www/test-laravel/releases/18`). Inside that folder the `storage` folder is actually a symbolic link to `/var/www/test-laravel/shared/storage`.

I was getting the following error,

[image: The stream or file "/var/www/test-laravel/releases/18/storage/logs/laravel-2020-06-25.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied]

After trying a few variations of permissions/owners/groups, out of frustration I manually ran `chmod -R 777` and `chown -R apache.apache` on not just the original storage folder but on all of the symlink folders as well.

This hasn't changed anything at all. I'm still getting the same error.

I don't think this should make a difference, but just for good measure I've run `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was SELinux.

I disabled SELinux, (`setenforce 0`) and after that it worked just fine. However, I know that disabling SELinux is not preferable, so I re-enabled SELinux (`setenforce 1`) and instead, I tried changing the label on the storage folder like so,

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage
```

And that worked! No more permission problems.